# Cannot create materialized view with ORDER BY clause in TimescaleDb 2.7.0

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

The timescale docs seem to suggest that since 2.7.0 it should be possible to make materialized views which include an order by clause. (See "timescale.finalized" option [here](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/continuous-aggregates/create_materialized_view/#create-materialized-view-continuous-aggregate) and "function support" [here](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/continuous-aggregates/about-continuous-aggregates/#function-support)).

However, I have not been able to get this to work for me. When I try to create my materialized view I get:

```
ERROR:  invalid continuous aggregate query
DETAIL:  ORDER BY is not supported in queries defining continuous aggregates.
HINT:  Use ORDER BY clauses in SELECTS from the continuous aggregate view instead.
```

Is there something fundamental I'm misunderstanding about how this should work?

Here is the full script:

```
> select extname, extversion from pg_extension where extname = 'timescaledb';

   extname   | extversion
-------------+------------
 timescaledb | 2.7.0
(1 row)


> CREATE TABLE stocks_real_time (
  time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  price DOUBLE PRECISION NULL
  );

CREATE TABLE


> SELECT create_hypertable('stocks_real_time','time');

       create_hypertable
-------------------------------
 (7,public,stocks_real_time,t)
(1 row)


> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mat_view_stocks_real_time
  WITH (timescaledb.continuous)
  AS (
    SELECT
      time_bucket('60 minutes', time) as bucketed_time,
      AVG(price) as price
    FROM stocks_real_time
    GROUP BY bucketed_time
    ORDER BY bucketed_time
  );

ERROR:  invalid continuous aggregate query
DETAIL:  ORDER BY is not supported in queries defining continuous aggregates.
HINT: Use ORDER BY clauses in SELECTS from the continuous aggregate view instead.
```

I still get the same error if I explicitly add "timescaledb.finalized=true" to the with clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(NB: I work at Timescale!)

We have an open issue to support this, and I think the confusion is because we now support *aggregates* with order by clauses in them, this means things like: `SELECT percentile_cont(price) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY time)` or `SELECT array_agg(foo ORDER BY time)`

So I think that is probably where the confusion is coming from, but like I said, we have an open issue to support that sort of order by. You can also apply the order by in the SELECT from the continuous aggregate though: ie `SELECT * FROM mat_view_stocks_real_time ORDER BY bucketed_time` and that should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks David, this clears it up for me.

We were hoping to avoid adding the ORDER BY to the select FROM the materialized view to avoid having to edit too much existing code, but it looks like we'll be exploring going this way.

Comment: You can also just add a view on top of the continuous aggregate that does the order by if that's the problem...

Comment: @ScottLangridge let me know if that helps as well! The way to do it would be something like `CREATE VIEW ordered as(SELECT * FROM mat_view_stocks_real_time ORDER BY bucketed_time)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David, that's definitely a clean solution. I think I'll have a play around before deciding what to go with from there.

Thanks again for your help!